# Send data as a json file with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, buffer

I'm trying to send some javascript object (as JSON data in a json file) with a command using discord.js. Yet It's not as easy as sending an image. I tried using [`AttachmentBuilder`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/main/AttachmentBuilder:Class) (with/without [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)), with and without the additional data being the name:

```js
const jsonFile = new AttachmentBuilder(JSON.stringify(data), {
    name: embedName + ".json",
  });
message.reply({ content: "Data:", files : [jsonFile]})
```

But I get this weird error no matter how i put my data:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator)')
    at DataResolver.resolveFile (C:\Users\___\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\DataResolver.js:117:24)
    at MessagePayload.resolveFile (C:\Users\___\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:260:54)
    at C:\Users\___\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:225:85
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MessagePayload.resolveFiles (C:\Users\___\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:225:56)
    at StringSelectMenuInteraction.reply (C:\Users\___\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:109:70)
    at module.exports.run (C:\Users\___\interactions\StringSelectMenu\select-embed.js:38:20)
    at async Object.run (C:\Users\___\events\interactionCreate.js:24:11)
    at async SkeeBot.<anonymous> (C:\Users\___\classes\SkeeBot.js:96:11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a buffer to stream the data to the builder. You can do so by using `Buffer.from(<target>)`. You can learn more about [buffers here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-buffer-in-node-js/) or access the [Node.js docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Example using your source:

```
const jsonFile = new AttachmentBuilder(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)), {
    name: embedName + ".json",
  });
```

Comment: damn i tried Buffer.from(data) and JSON.stringify(data) alone but never thought of both.